# self login bot , stay logged, browse site

Tags: php, curl, bots

i am creating a bot in PHP that can log in into a site and stay logged. But it's not working.
i am using this code. but it's not working.

```
<?php  
$curl = curl_init("http://www.site.com/login.php");
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "usr=username&pswd=password");
curl_exec($curl);
echo curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

i have also tried this but it's also not working

```
<?php
$fields = array(
    "login"=>"username",
    "pass"=>"passowrd"
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.site.com/login.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: most sites don't allow allow this in their terms, and many actively try to stop it

Comment: Thank goodness it's not that easy.

Comment: i will first test it for my own site then i will apply it on others, thing is that how to code this bot. i need this bot badly....

Comment: Acually it's often not that difficult. Investigate how your browser stays logged in. However, if you can't figure it out from the dozens of duplicates / from the search; then you should keep working on simpler programming tasks for now.

Comment: i need all the money in the world badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use these to save their cookie:

```
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => 'data/cookies/x.tmp',
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => 'data/cookies/x.tmp',
```

Also, some times require a cookie to be set before the login is sent. This is often an issue. Often also worth setting:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 0,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => 0,
```